# interceptty error when executing

Tags: linux, unix, tty

I want to listen to a certain device on my linux system. therefore I am using interceptty. When I call:

`mv ttyO0 ttyO0-orig`

and then

`./interceptty -o ttyO0.out /dev/ttyO0-orig /dev/ttyO0 &`

I get the error: `Couldn't openpty: No such file or directry`

What does this mean? The file ttyO0-orig is available. Or is the error somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [manual page](http://www.suspectclass.com/sgifford/interceptty/interceptty.html), it appears to be complaining about the *front device*, which does not exist (since you moved it):

```
Usage: ./interceptty [-V] [-qvl] [-s back-set] [-o output-file] 
                  [-p pty-dev] [-t tty-dev] 
                  [-m [pty-owner,[pty-group,]]pty-mode]
                  [-u uid] [-g gid] [-/ chroot-dir]
                  back-device front-device
```

Comment: But isn't it supposed to be moved as this front device is being emulated by interceptty?